# Dissolution of lead chloride because of the formation of- Na2PbO2 or [Pb(OH)4]-2?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I read that $\ce{NaOH}$ precipitates lead hydroxide which dissolves with excess hydroxide.

In some sources, I read that lead chloride dissolves due to the formation of complex $\ce{[Pb(OH)4]^2-}$ but my teacher taught that it is because of the formation of $\ce{Na2PbO2}$

I don't think that both are same. I cannot find much information about $\ce{Na2PbO2}$ either.

Which of these two is actually formed?

Answer (score 2):

Lead hydroxide do dissolve in excess of alkali solution forming complex ([the solution becomes clear](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Analytical_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Analytical_Chemistry)/Qualitative_Analysis/Characteristic_Reactions_of_Select_Metal_Ions/Characteristic_Reactions_of_Lead_Ions_(Pb%C2%B2%E2%81%BA))):

$$\ce{Pb(OH)2(s) + 2OH-(aq) -> [Pb(OH)4]^2-(aq)}$$

There can be confusion because some articles(e.g. [here](https://www.chemguide.co.uk/inorganic/group4/lead.html)) says it lead to formation of sodium plumbate(II) but plumbate is poorly defined as it can considered lead oxyanion or [oxides of lead](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/163800/17368).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead(II)_hydroxide) further mentions:

> In solution, lead(II) hydroxide is a somewhat weak base, forming
> lead(II) ion, $\ce{Pb^2+}$ under weakly acidic conditions. This cation
> hydrolyzes and under progressively increasing alkaline conditions,
> forms $\ce{Pb(OH)+}$, $\ce{Pb(OH)2(aq)}$, $\ce{Pb(OH)3−}$, and other
> polynuclear species like $\ce{Pb4(OH)4^4+}$, $\ce{Pb3(OH)4^2+}$,
> $\ce{Pb6O(OH)6^4+}$