Fe3O4 as a mixed oxide
Fe3O4 is a mixed oxide. This compound can be formed by different chemical means. Will mixing FeO and Fe2O3 at room temperature or at certain conditions form Fe3O4 ? Is there any possibilities ?
And is it called a mixed oxide because it has both Fe3+ and Fe2+ in its structure or because it is a mixture of FeO and Fe2O3 ?

And related Pb3O4: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/163777/why-is-pb3o4-called-leadii-iv-oxide

Iron(II,III) oxide $\ce{Fe3O4}$ :

... has a cubic inverse spinel group structure which consists of a cubic close packed array of oxide ions where all of the $\ce{Fe^2+}$ ions occupy half of the octahedral sites and the $\ce{Fe^3+}$ are split evenly across the remaining octahedral sites and the tetrahedral sites.
The Massart method of preparation of magnetite as a ferrofluid, is convenient in the laboratory: mix iron(II) chloride and iron(III) chloride in the presence of sodium hydroxide.

\begin{align}
\ce{FeCl2(aq) + 2 FeCl3(aq) + 8 NaOH(aq) &-> Fe(OH)2(s) + 2 Fe(OH)3(s) +  8 NaCl(aq)}\\
\ce{Fe(OH)2(s) + 2 Fe(OH)3(s) &->  4 H2O(l) + Fe3O4(s)}
\end{align}
(For more, see this Ferrofluid preparation by my favorite chemist youtuber NileRed.)
If you made a stoichiometric mixture 1:1 of finely milled $\ce{FeO}$ and $\ce{Fe2O3}$ and heated them enough in a sealed container, you would get $\ce{Fe3O4}$. But it would be via $\ce{Fe2O3}$ releasing oxygen, becoming $\ce{Fe3O4}$ and $\ce{FeO}$ capturing that oxygen, becoming $\ce{Fe3O4}$ too.
Note that these oxides are not exactly stoichiometric. E.g. the typical empirical composition of $\ce{FeO}$ is $\ce{Fe_{0.93}O}$.

Fe3O4 is cubic and Fe2O3 is rhomboedric.

Thanks for the addition.
